# Bypassing Controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, controller

Im using Rails 2.3.5 and I have a model, let's call it Post. I used named scopes to apply different kinds of sorts on Post. For example, in the Post model I have possibility to rank posts by its scores:

```
named_scope :order_by_acception_rate_desc,
Proc.new { |limit| { :limit => limit, :order => "acception_rate desc" } }
```

In the Post Controller I have:

```
def best
    @best_posts = Post.order_by_acception_rate_desc(10)
end
```

In the view I just render this collection @best_posts:

```
<%= render :partial => "post", :collection => @best_posts
```

Currently my application is working like that, but actually I do not need to have the method "best" in the Controller, and I could move it to the Model Post doing like:

```
def self.best
    self.order_by_acception_rate_desc(10)
end
```

and then in the view I would render the collection like:

```
<%= render :partial => "post", :collection => Post.best
```

I do not know which approach is better, but using the ranking methods in the Model, I could avoid to create routes for each one of ranking methods. What approach is better, is there any better approach than these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with according to Rails conventions the logic should be separated,

1. controllers handle permissions, auth/authorization, assign instance/class variables
2. helpers handle html logic what to show/hide to user
3. views should not provide any logic, permissions check. think about it from designer's point of view
4. models handle data collection/manipulation over ORM

I'd like to ask you to try:

```
#helper
def self.best(limit)
  all(:limit => limit, :order => "acception_rate desc")
end

#controller
@best_posts = Post.best

#view
<%= render :partial => "post", :collection => @best_posts %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not bypass the controller and include much logic in your view.

You could keep a single route and filter the `Post` model depending on one of the `params`.

You don't tell enough here to answer more clearly but you have the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave just the view file and it should work.